# Label a whole numpy array with one label on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I would like to label a whole numpy array with only one label.
The following code for example creates 6 (=2+4) labels instead of only 2 labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.rand(10,2)
b = np.random.rand(10,4)


plt.figure()
plt.plot(a, 'blue', label = 'a')
plt.plot(b, 'red', label = 'b')
plt.legend()
```

How should the code above be modified to create only 2 legend labels, 'a' and 'b'?

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify how many lines you expect to be drawn from the array `a` or `b`?

Comment: You are plotting 6 lines. You get 6 labels.

Comment: @medium-dimensional I would like to get one label per numpy.array, or one label per color, while plotting 2 blue lines (labeled a ) and 4 red lines (labeled b), i.e. the graph should stay the same, the legend should be only one legend blue line - a, one legend red line - b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a_lines = plt.plot(a, c='blue')
b_lines = plt.plot(b, c='red')
plt.legend(handles=[a_lines[0], b_lines[0]], labels=['a', 'b'])
```